# SolidJs: How to trigger createEffect to update a signal from createResource?

Tags: typescript, vite, solid-js

I'm trying to get createEffect to update my userDetails signal with the data retrieved from createResource. However, when the page launches, the createEffect only runs the first initial time and doesn't ever get the value from the createResource function. I know that there's something I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure out what exactly.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class UserDetails {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public name: string,
        public age: number,
        public email: string,
    ){}
}

const emptyUserDetails = (): UserDetails => ({
    id: '1234',
    name: 'Test User',
    age: 0,
    email: 'testUser@email.com',
});

const loadUserDetailsFromAPI = async(businessId: string) => {
    let res = await fetch(`users-URl/${businessId}`, {
        method: 'GET',
    })
        .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(res.statusText)
        }
        if (res.status === 200) {
            return res.json() as Promise<UserDetails>
        }
        return ;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
    console.log("res: ", res);

    return res;
}

export default function UsersPage() {
    const params = useParams();

    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = createSignal<UserDetails>(emptyUserDetails());
    const [userDetailsData] = createResource(params.id, loadUserDetailsFromAPI);

    createEffect(() => {
        console.log(userDetailsData(), userDetailsData.loading);

        if (userDetailsData() != null && !userDetailsData.loading) {
            setUserDetails(userDetailsData()!);
            return;
        }
    });

    return (
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-3">
            <span>userDetails().id</span>
            <span>userDetails().name</span>
            <span>userDetails().age</span>
            <span>userDetails().email</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the correct way to guard against the data (user) from createResource.

From the SolidJS API:

> Show can also be used with a callback that returns a null asserted
> accessor. Remember to only use this accessor when the condition is
> true or it will throw.
>
> ```
> <Show when={state.user} fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
>   {(user) => <div>{user().firstName}</div>}
> </Show>
> ```
>
> Show can also be used as a way of keying blocks to a specific data
> model. Ex the function is re-executed whenever the user model is
> replaced.

```
import { createResource, Suspense, Show } from "solid-js";
import { useParams } from "solid-start";

interface IUserDetails{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  images: string[];
}

class UserDetails {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  images: string[];
  constructor( {id, name, images}: IUserDetails) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.images = images;
  }
}

const loadUserDetailsFromAPI = async(businessId: string) => {
  let res = await fetch(`some-user-api/${businessId}`)
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  if (res && res.status === 200) {
    const json = res.json() as Promise<IUserDetails>
    return new UserDetails(await json);
  }

  return;
}

export default function UsersPage() {
  const params = useParams();
  const [userDetails] = createResource(params.id, loadUserDetailsFromAPI);

  return (<Suspense fallback= {<p> Loading...</p>}>
    <Show when={userDetails()}>
      {(userDetails) => <div>
      <span>userDetails().id</span>
      <span>userDetails().name</span>
        <div>
          <span>userDetails().images[0]</span>
          <span>userDetails().images[1]</span>
          <span>userDetails().images[2]</span>
        </div>
      </div>}
    </Show>
  </Suspense>);
}
```

Comment: You need to guard against object being null untill request resolves. So this sdoes not work.

Comment: @snnsnn yea you're right I just fixed it. Appreciate it

Comment: No you did not, you supressed  it using !, lost type safety. Component is broken.

Comment: @snnsnn updated (again) my solution so that it does type cast correctly. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Resource created by `createResource` fetches the remote resource upon creation, you don't need to call it inside any effect. That was your first mistake. Also the returned value is a signal, you don't need to create another one to store values.

The second one is `createResource` returns a array, where the first item is a getter that returns the data. It has properties to extract other information related to the resource like its state, or error if it fails. So all and all you are not following the API. Here is how you do it:

```js
export const App = () => {
  const [data] = createResource(fethcer);

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Match when={data.state === 'pending'}>Pending</Match>
      <Match when={data.state === 'errored'}>Errored</Match>
      <Match when={data.state === 'ready'}>{JSON.stringify(data())}</Match>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

You check the API: https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createresource

Here is a detailed explanation:

Resource data requires you to wrap it in a guard clause because when it is read the first time, it will be undefined. Resource under Suspense is read twice, one for tracking and one for the final rendering.

Type casting is needed for suppressing type errors by eliminating the undefined from T because data for a resource is T | undefined. Once it is resolved, it is T. Inside Show, data is always T, because you are guarding against undefined. But typescript can not see through the Show, asking you to guard it, that is why you need to use optional chaining operator ? or casting via ! to suppress the type error.

Comment: Thank for this answer! The api was unclear to me so I wasn't sure how to hook everything up in a way that Typescript didn't give me and error of `object possibly undefined` when using userDetails() in my example. However, I did figure out how to set it up in my answer.

Comment: Hey @snnsnn, it doesn't solve my problem. My updated answer is what I needed

Comment: @CarloNyte You need to cast to type with ! or use ?, like user.?name because neither Suspende or Switch/Match can enforce guard like an if statement.

Comment: Updated my answer (again ) with a cleaner and better solution. Of course the answer was right in the SolidJs docs all along  ‍♂️